# How do I display multiple columns from 3 Different tables in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 3 tables:

> `Reservation`, `Trip`, `Customer`

I only need to display the trip name, trip type, customer first name, customer last name of the customers who have multiple reservations

Sort of like this

**Reservation table**

> Reservation_ID ... ... .. Customer_Num
>
> 1. 16001  101
> 2. 16002  101
> 3. 16003  102
> 4. 16004  103
> 5. 16005  103

**Customer table**

> Customer_ID ... ... .. Customer_Num
>
> 1. 30                   101
> 2. 31                   102
> 3. 32                   103

Customer table's primary ID is `customer_ID` and has a column name of 
`Customer_Num`. this column name is also in the `reservation` table.

Reservation table's primary id is `Reservation_ID`

I’ve tried:

```
SELECT Customer.First_Name, Customer.Last_Name, Trip.Trip_Name, Trip.Type, Reservation.Customer_Num COUNT(Reservation.Customer_Num
FROM Reservation, Customer, Trip
WHERE Reservation.Customer_Num = Customer.Customer_Num
HAVING COUNT(Reservation.Customer_Num) > 1
GROUP BY Customer.First_Name, Customer.Last_Name, Trip.Trip_Name, Trip.Type, Reservation.Customer_Num;
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share the sample data and expected result.

Comment: Hi @MTcodes and where is the Trip table ? Also, do show us the code you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Presumming in your TRIP table you have columns as trip name, trip type, You may try below query -

```
SELECT Customer.First_Name
      ,Customer.Last_Name
      ,Trip.Trip_Name
      ,Trip.Type
      ,Reservation.Customer_Num
      ,COUNT(Reservation.Customer_Num) Customer_Num_Cnt
FROM Reservation R
INNER JOIN Customer C ON Reservation.Customer_Num = Customer.Customer_Num
INNER JOIN Trip T ON R.TRIP_ID = T.TRIP_ID
GROUP BY Customer.First_Name
        ,Customer.Last_Name
        ,Trip.Trip_Name
        ,Trip.Type
        ,Reservation.Customer_Num
-- HAVING COUNT(Reservation.Customer_Num) > 1;
```

If this doesn't fulfil your requirements, Please share the complete structure of TRIP table and CUSTOMER table.

Comment: I added the trip table as well as the other two tables, just for clarification.

Comment: used the code but had to remove the 'C' 'R' and 'T' after each table name and just use the full table name. it says no data found

Comment: SELECT CUSTOMER.FIRST_NAME, CUSTOMER.LAST_NAME, TRIP.TRIP_NAME, TRIP.TYPE, RESERVATION.CUSTOMER_NUM, COUNT(RESERVATION.CUSTOMER_NUM) CUSTOMER_NUM_CNT
FROM RESERVATION
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER ON RESERVATION.CUSTOMER_NUM = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NUM
INNER JOIN TRIP ON RESERVATION.TRIP_ID = TRIP.TRIP_ID
GROUP BY CUSTOMER.FIRST_NAME, CUSTOMER.LAST_NAME, TRIP.TRIP_NAME, TRIP.TYPE, RESERVATION.CUSTOMER_NUM
HAVING COUNT(RESERVATION.CUSTOMER_NUM) > 1;

Comment: It might be possible that HAVING condition is filtering all the records as there might be no customers who have more than 2 entries in Reservation table. Just remove the HAVING clause and try again. For your convenience, I have updated the query to comment the Having clause.

Comment: Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, presuming that Trip table using Customer_num field as foreign key

```
select A.Customer_id, A.Name, A.Last_name, B.name, B.type from Customer as A
where Customer_id in 
    (select Customer_Num from Reservation group by Customer_Num having count(Customer_Num) > 1)
left join Trip as B on Trip.Customer_Num = Customer.Customer_Num
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT t.*, c.*
FROM reservation r INNER JOIN
     customer c
     ON c.Customer_Num = r.Customer_Num INNER JOIN
     trip t
     ON . . .
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM reservation r1 
              WHERE r1.customer_no = r.customer_no AND 
                    r1.Reservation_ID <> r.Reservation_ID 
             );
```

You need to adjust the `ON` clause for Trip table as you didn't specified the table information.

Answer (score 0):

This displays the results making it so I can pick which names have more than one reservation. In the reservation table it lists the customer num who has more than one reservation but I'm not sure why it wasn't working.

SELECT CUSTOMER.FIRST_NAME, CUSTOMER.LAST_NAME, TRIP.TRIP_NAME, TRIP.TYPE, RESERVATION.CUSTOMER_NUM, COUNT(RESERVATION.CUSTOMER_NUM) CUSTOMER_NUM_CNT

FROM RESERVATION

INNER JOIN CUSTOMER ON CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NUM = RESERVATION.CUSTOMER_NUM
INNER JOIN TRIP ON  RESERVATION.TRIP_ID = TRIP.TRIP_ID

GROUP BY CUSTOMER.FIRST_NAME, CUSTOMER.LAST_NAME, TRIP.TRIP_NAME, TRIP.TYPE, RESERVATION.CUSTOMER_NUM
commented out--HAVING COUNT(RESERVATION.CUSTOMER_NUM) > 1;

[image]